# append a word to the end of a line in txt file

Tags: command-line, files, grep, sed

I have a file that should have **"OK"** at the end of a certain line

the line that should be modified is the first line not ending with **"OK"**

I can grep the file to get the line to be modified using the following code

```
grep -vnm 1 OK '/content2'
```

i need a help in add the pattern OK to the end of this line

Example:

if the file content has the following lines

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa OK
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb OK  
cccccccccccccc  
dddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeee OK
```

i need to add OK to the line contains the `cccccccccccc` only

Comment: sample of input & output needed.

Comment: @KasiyA added example to the question

Comment: You say that 'the line that should be modified is the next line to the last one ends with "OK"'. In this case the last one that ends with OK is the last line - `eeeeeeeeeeeeee OK`. So why would you add to `cccccccccccccc`?

Comment: @KasiyA No need to be so abrasive. The question might have been formulated somewhat more clearly (notably to remove the ambiguity of what to do in the edge case of there being _no_ line ending in OK), but it explicitly excludes your interpretation of adding OK to the first non-OK line _as well as to every subsequent line_, as it explicitly states "a certain line [...] only".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following `awk` program:

```
awk -v s=" OK" '/OK$/ { print; } !/OK$/ { print $0 s; s=""; }'
```

It works like this:

```
/OK$/ { print; }
```

prints out any line ending in `OK` as is, whereas

```
!/OK$/ { print $0 s; s=""; }
```

prints out any line *not* ending in `OK` with the value of variable `s` appended.

Variable `s` initially is the string `' OK'`. It changes to the empty string after the first encounter of a line not ending in `OK`.

**Update**

Even more concisely:

```
awk -v s=" OK" '!/OK$/ { print $0 s; s=""; } /OK$/'
```

eliminates the `{ print; }` action for the `/OK$/` condition, as `{ print; }` is the default action.

**Correction**

Looking at the question again, it does not say the `OK` should be added to the first line not having `OK`, but instead to the first line not having an `OK` which follows a line that **does** have an `OK`. So, we must keep a variable, `c` that flags that at least one `OK` line has been seen, and a variable `d` that flags that we are done:

```
awk ' /OK$/ { if (!d) c=1; } 
     !/OK$/ { if (c) d=1; } 
     c && d { s=" OK"; c=0; }
     { print $0 s; s=""; }'
```

Comment: Would the downvoter please comment on what the issue is with this answer?

Comment: great! and if there were more sections, `/OK$/ { print; s="OK";}` do the job, isn't it?

Comment: I think the downvote might have been because on the sample text, it doesn't work correctly because the edit added several spaces to the end of two lines (probably unintentionally). If you remove those spaces it works nicely, although it does add an extra space to the end of the ddddd line, not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: Ah, that is a consequence of the comma in the print command. It inserts a space. This can be fixed by using `print $0s;` instead of `print $0,s;`, and setting `s=" OK"` at the start. Will fix.

Comment: @Letizia Yes, that's pretty. Made me realise one ambiguity though: the question specifies that `OK` should be added to the first line not having `OK` _after_ a line _having_ OK. The solution as it is will add `OK` to the first line not having `OK`, regardless of whether an `OK` line occurred before. Adding fix.

Comment: @zwets can you please tell me how to use it with the file ( /home/fatmind/content2 ) as I used it this way ((awk ' /OK$/ { if (!d) c=1; } !/OK$/ { if (c) d=1; } c && d { s=" OK"; c=0; } { print $0 s; s=""; }' /home/fatmind/Desktop/content2))

but all what happens is like cat the file without modifications ???

Comment: @FatMind That works just fine when I run it (though note that you cannot use the double parentheses in bash). Are the letters "OK" the very last characters on the line, i.e. no white space after OK?

Comment: @zwets yes  you are right  the files were ending with (OK) so i changed it to be OK , and to save to the file i added a small part , if you have better way i will appreciate if you tell me 

awk ' /OK$/ { if (!d) c=1; } !/OK$/ { if (c) d=1; } c && d { s=" OK"; c=0; } { print $0 s; s=""; }' ~/Desktop/content > ~/Desktop/content2 ; mv ~/Desktop/content2 ~/Desktop/content

Comment: one thing only if the files does not have any line with OK at the end , i t will not modify any thing , but it's ok  and many thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
sed '0,/[^O][^K]$/{s/[^O][^K]$/& OK/}' filename
```

where `filename` is the name of your input file name.

Comment: ccccc is only for example it can be any thing ,the condition for the line that should be changed (it's the first line that dos not contain OK at the end of it)

Comment: Only the first line or all lines that don't have OK ?

Comment: only the first line